# Most efficient way to mutate an item in array of objects? [VUEX]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I read the official Vuex example of how to mutate the state of element in array of objects data.

```
editTodo (state, { todo, text = todo.text, done = todo.done }) {
    const index = state.todos.indexOf(todo)

    state.todos.splice(index, 1, {
      ...todo,
      text,
      done
    })
  }
```

It seems a bit an overkill to find the index first (first loop), perform a splice and perform a copy with spread operator `...todo` (would it be considered a second loop?).

Going by the docs:

> When adding new properties to an Object, you should either:
> Use `Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123)`, or Replace that Object with a fresh one. For example, using the object spread syntax: `state.obj = { ...state.obj, newProp: 123 }`

There are only two ways to set / update properties to object.

In bigger data scenario that is causing some performance issues. Is there any better (more efficient) way to update an element in array of objects?

Comment: Is this _actually_ causing performance issues? If you needed to do it in one pass you and you're just changing an item that already exists (i.e., not adding one) you could `map` the todos, like `state.todos.map(todo => todo === todo ? { ...todo, text, done } : todo)`

Comment: It is causing performance issues if you commit editTodo thousands times, one by one. Would it be better to gather all changed todos in a single `newTodos` and replace the `state.todos` with `newTodos` once?

Comment: How do thousands of todos change at once in your app? If the question is just hypothetical, how would that many records need changing in any situation?  If they are loaded from somewhere else, reset the whole collection.